# Typo3, TCA forms view depending on the chosen option

Tags: typo3, typo3-tca

I have made in backend a TCA form, what will change depending of the value in select field "type":

This select field contains basically the options:

- rte text
- url
- picture

I can make the system working so, that when "rte text" is chosen, it shows specified fields for "rte text", when url is chosen it shows specified fields for "url" etc..

In my case the content is always saved in database in field "content" and the selected type is saved in field "type".

My problem is that I have not found a way to change the "content" form field / configuration, depending on the selected type.

For example when I choose "rte text" it should use for the content field this kind of configuration (rich text editor):

```
'content' => array (        
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'Content',       
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => '30',
            'rows' => '5',
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING' => 2,
                'RTE' => array(
                    'notNewRecords' => 1,
                    'RTEonly'       => 1,
                    'type'          => 'script',
                    'title'         => 'Full screen Rich Text Editing|Formatteret redigering i hele vinduet',
                    'icon'          => 'wizard_rte2.gif',
                    'script'        => 'wizard_rte.php',
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
```

and when I choose "picture" it should use for the content field this kind of configuration (file uploader):

```
'content' => array (        
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'Content',       
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'group',
            'internal_type' => 'file',
            'allowed' => '',    
            'disallowed' => 'php,php3', 
            'max_size' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['maxFileSize'], 
            'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/tx_uploadshere',
            'size' => 1,    
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 1,
        )
    ),
```

Is there a way to change that configuration depending of the value in the selectbox. I have tried to put two contents in an array but haven't got it working on that way.

Comment: It is possible to achieve what you want with an extra bit of PHP but I don't think it's correct to mix different content in one table field. I think that the approach suggested by @konsolenfreddy would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot change the properties of a single field via `type`.

You can however influence what's being displayed. So you can configure two independent fields and switch the display:

**ext_tables.php**:

```
$TCA['tx_yourextension_yourtable'] = array(
    'ctrl' => array(
        //...
        'type'=>'type',
        //...
    ),
);
```

**TCA.php**:

```
$TCA['tx_yourextension_yourtable'] = array(
    'ctrl' => $TCA['tx_yourextension_yourtable']['ctrl'],
    'types' => array(
        0 => array('showitem' => 'content_rte'),
        1 => array('showitem' => 'content_image'),
    ),
    'columns' => array(
        'content_rte' => array(
            'exclude' => 0,
            'label' => 'Content',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'cols' => '30',
                'rows' => '5',
                'wizards' => array(
                    '_PADDING' => 2,
                    'RTE' => array(
                        'notNewRecords' => 1,
                        'RTEonly' => 1,
                        'type' => 'script',
                        'title' => 'Full screen Rich Text Editing|Formatteret redigering i hele vinduet',
                        'icon' => 'wizard_rte2.gif',
                        'script' => 'wizard_rte.php',
                    ),
                ),
            )
        ),
        'content_upload' => array(
            'exclude' => 0,
            'label' => 'Content',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'group',
                'internal_type' => 'file',
                'allowed' => '',
                'disallowed' => 'php,php3',
                'max_size' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['maxFileSize'],
                'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/tx_uploadshere',
                'size' => 1,
                'minitems' => 0,
                'maxitems' => 1,
            )
        ),
    ),
    // ...
);
```

(Note: I've removed system fields like `hidden`, `sys_language_uid` etc. for simplicity's sake)